# Why is the quiet option -q in OSX security command not quieting anything?

Tags: macos, command-line, keychain

I'm using the OSX command line tool security to remove an entry from the keychain like this: `security -q delete-generic-password -l "name.of.my.app"`

The `-q` is supposed to remove all stdout and stderr output, but when I run the command, I still get 20 lines of text in my terminal.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[The manual](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/security/) says:

> `-q`       Will make `security` less verbose.

"Less verbose" is not necessarily completely silent.

A general way to discard stdout and stderr is

```
whatever >/dev/null 2>&1
```